# Spring unmarshal and wire XML into bean

Tags: spring, jaxb2

Given a static XML (as defined below) can you configure spring to unmarshal and load the bean without using a factory method. More specifically is it possible to in some way configure it in application context so that what the application loads the bean automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<outerbean>
    <age>20</age>
    <innerbean>
        <innerName>Inner123</innerName>
        <innerAge>10</innerAge>
    </innerbean>
</outerbean>


@XmlRootElement(name="outerbean")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @Component
public class OuterBean {

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private int age;

    @XmlElement(name="innerbean")
    private InnerBean innerBean;

    ....
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "innerbean")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class InnerBean {

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String innerName; 

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private int innerAge;

....    
}
```

Comment: Why not use `<bean>` in spring context?

Comment: The 'actual' XML has quite a few fields. Using JAXBContext unmarshaller works fine. I am just trying to figure out if there is a better (preferably automated) way of doing this.

Comment: Nothing comes to my mind in this case except of writing your own JAXB-backed factory, that will parse file and register those beans in context.

Comment: So the best I have comeup with so far is to wire it up using factory bean which takes a file as input in constructor. then load OuterBean using factory method.. Which works fine.. but I cant help but think there has to be a better way